# find closest elements in unequal sized non-integer matlab arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have 2 matrices of t=[1,2880000] and t1=[1,143986].

I am trying find out which elements are closest between these two arrays. I tried the following code which works fine on smaller arrays but not on such large arrays.

```
% create two similar sized matrix and find out difference between each element
t1_m=repmat(t1', size(t)); 
t_m=repmat(t, size(t1'));
diff_m=abs(t_m-t1_m);
ind1=find(diff_m<1e-5);
```

This gives out of memory problem with repmat. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't hold 2880000 x 143986 values in memory. You need to loop over one of the two vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you are given two sets of numbers and you need to find the pairs which are closest one another.

This is in principle a quadratic problem, although, it can be reduced to a NlogN (in time)  problem via sorting (provided your arrays are "sufficiently sparse").

let

```
  A = rand(1000,1) 
  B = rand(1100,1)
```

be the two sets of yours.

We construct a labeled juxtaposed array `C` of the two

```
C = [A ones(size(A)) ;
     B 2*ones(size(B))]
```

so at the moment the first column of `C` contains the elements of `A` (marked by a `1` in the second column) and the elements of `B` (labeled by a `2`). We sort `C` as to have close element close one another

```
D = sortrows(C).
```

Now if we diff `D` we have something like

```
>> E = abs(diff(D))

   0.000694103278079                   0
   0.000153057031699                   0
   0.000557077905541                   0
   0.001520045249172   1.000000000000000
   0.000249084264359   1.000000000000000
   0.000148379610173                   0
   0.000013761461813   1.000000000000000
```

which is telling us that whenever a `1` comes out we are calculating the difference between **close** elements of the two different sets.  So we find such elements by

```
  idx_good = find(E(:,1) < 1e-5 & E(:,2) == 1)
```

and we write them down as

```
  >> [D((idx_good),1) D((idx_good)+1)]

  ans =

   0.042652410911143   0.042659855935049
   0.060466771939828   0.060471179169894
   0.075966691690842   0.075967361294136
   0.119207259421287   0.119214541054191
   0.146514856442232   0.146514910614890
   0.205672339463963   0.205674521464760
   0.208461358751314   0.208470223305320
   0.234779913372406   0.234782640662848
```

which contains an element from `A` in the first column and an element from `B` in the second column.

Well, this isn't enough though, as we found just some of the elements satisfying this property (**it is sufficient if you are looking at the absolute closest pair, anyway**).

Hence, we have to replay the trick applying a growing offset in the `diff` as many times as necessary in order to *see* all possible close pairs which are sufficiently close. In other words, one can define a function

```
 diff_ext = @(m,amount) m(1:end-amount,:) - m(1+amount:end,:);
```

to be used instead of `diff`, for growing integer values of `amount` such that

```
abs(diff_ext(D,amount))
```

admits elements smaller than your threshold.

The elements which you found must then added at the set of the close differences.

Comment: It worked well for smaller matrices but there was memory problem with larger matrices.So I had to use for loop for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can simply use:

```
% handle if t,t1 have different length
sz = min(size(t, 2), size(t1, 2));
t2 = t(1:sz);
t3 = t1(1:sz);

[dist,ind] = min(abs(t2-t3)) % ind gives you the index, dist is min-difference
```

---

Test case:

```
t=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1];
t1=[0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7];
```

You will get:

```
dist =

    0.3000


ind =

     4
```

---

**Note:** it will give you the last index if multiple indexes with the min-difference.

Comment: The values are like a=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1] and b=[0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7] so this does not work

Comment: @dissw.geek9 Updated the answer. Check it out.